# Improvement in performance

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get function application based on lagging/forwarding. I use extensively `data.table` and I even have working code, but knowing power of `data.table` I think there must be a simpler way to achieve the same with possibly improving the performance (I do a lot of creation of variables inside the functions). Below is working code of functions (available in https://gist.github.com/tomaskrehlik/5262087#file-gistfile1-r )

```
# Lag-function lags the given variable by the date_variable

lag_variable <- function(data, variable, lags, date_variable = c("Date")) {
    if (lags == 0) {
      return(data)
    }
    if (lags>0) {
      name <- "lag"
    } else {
      name <- "forward"
    }
    require(data.table)
    setkeyv(data, date_variable)
    if (lags>0) {
      data[,index:=seq(1:.N)]  
    } else {
      data[,index:=rev(seq(1:.N))]
    }
    setkeyv(data, "index")
    lags <- abs(lags)
    position <- which(names(data)==variable)
    for ( j in 1:lags ) {
      lagname <- paste(variable,"_",name,j,sep="")
      lag <- paste("data[, ",lagname,":=data[list(index-",j,"), ",variable,", roll=TRUE][[",position,"L]]]", sep = "")
      eval(parse( text = lag ))
    }
    setkeyv(data, date_variable)
    data[,index:=NULL]
}

# window_func applies the function to the lagged or forwarded variables created by lag_variable
window_func <- function(data, func.name, variable, direction = "window", steps, date_variable = c("Date"), clean = TRUE) {
    require(data.table)
    require(stringr)
    transform <- match.fun(func.name)
    l <- length(names(data))
    if (direction == "forward") {
      lag_variable(data, variable, -steps, date_variable)
      cols <- which((!(is.na(str_match(names(a), paste(variable,"_forward(",paste(1:steps,collapse="|"),")",sep=""))[,1])))*1==1)
    } else {
      if (direction == "backward") {
        lag_variable(data, variable, steps, date_variable)
        cols <- which((!(is.na(str_match(names(a), paste(variable,"_lag(",paste(1:steps,collapse="|"),")",sep=""))[,1])))*1==1)
      } else {
        if (direction == "window") {
          lag_variable(data, variable, -steps, date_variable)
          lag_variable(data, variable, steps, date_variable)
          cols <- which((!(is.na(str_match(names(a), paste(variable,"_lag(",paste(1:steps,collapse="|"),")",sep=""))[,1])))*1==1)
          cols <- c(cols,which((!(is.na(str_match(names(a), paste(variable,"_forward(",paste(1:steps,collapse="|"),")",sep=""))[,1])))*1==1))
        } else {
          stop("The direction must be either backward, forward or window.")
        }
      }
    }
    data[,transf := apply(data[,cols, with=FALSE], 1, transform)]
    if (clean) {
      data[,cols:=NULL,with=FALSE]
    }
    return(data)
}

# Typical use:
# I have a data.table DT with variables Date (class IDate), value1, value2
# I want to get cumulative sum of next five days
# window_func(DT, "sum", "value1", direction = "forward", steps = 5)
```

**Edit:** Sample data can be created by:

```
a <- data.table(Date = 1:1000, value = rnorm(1000))
```

For each Date (which, here, are integers just for an example, does not matter much), I want to create the *sum of next ten observations*. To run the code and get output, do:

```
window_func(data = a, func.name = "sum", variable = "value", 
      direction = "forward", steps = 10, date_variable = "Date", clean = TRUE)
```

The function first takes the variable and creates ten lagged variables (using function `lag_variable`) and then applies function column-wise and cleans after itself. Code is bloated because I sometimes need to use functions only on lag observations, sometimes on forward observations and sometimes on both, which is called window.

Any suggestions how to implement this better? My code seems to be somehow too big.

Comment: Can we have some data? Also, can you explain what your code is trying to achieve in a few words if possible? And also the output for your sample data (if your code is fully functional to obtain the output, I don't mind looking at the output myself).

Comment: tomaskrehlik, why don't you edit your post to add this information? I can read this for sure. But it's much better to edit. I'll try to understand your code now.

Comment: tomaskrehlik, Sounds alright to me. The `data.table` part seems to be nicely handled. My minor comments would be to change `seq(1:.N)` to `seq_len(.N)` :). Also, some `if - else` statements could be changed to `ifelse(condition, "", "")`. Also, maybe you might want to add `na.rm = TRUE` for `sum`...? Not sure.

Comment: I actually have the `na.rm` somewhere else in the code. :) I was rather hoping there is some native `data.table` solution... Thanks for comments, I will surely make use of them.

Comment: If I understand your code right, you create `steps/lags` number of columns and then apply the function `transform`. It seems a simple issue. But making it more general costs you lines! :)

Comment: Yes, exactly. If I were be doing it on small dataset, I wouldn't care much, but with GBs of data I thought I might save some time by better implementation. (I don't understand much the internals of `data.table` but I guess that by creating column `data.table` copies the data whereas some native rolling function might only be creating the column in less time-demanding way.)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the rest of your function, but you can get your lagged sum rather efficiently as follows:

```
a[ , lagSum := 
       a[, list(sum=sum(value)), by=list(grp=(Date+lag-i) %/% lag)] [grp!=0, sum]
   , by=list(i=Date %% lag)]
```

---

eg:

```
set.seed(1)
a[ , lagSum := 
       a[, list(sum=sum(value)), by=list(grp=(Date+lag-i) %/% lag)] [grp!=0, sum]
   , by=list(i=Date %% lag)]

> a
      Date      value      lagSum
   1:    1 -0.6264538  1.32202781
   2:    2  0.1836433  3.46026279
   3:    3 -0.8356286  3.66646270
   4:    4  1.5952808  3.88085074
   5:    5  0.3295078  0.07087005
  ---                            
 996:  996 -0.3132929 -3.79332038
 997:  997 -0.8806707 -3.48002750
 998:  998 -0.4192869 -2.59935677
 999:  999 -1.4827517 -2.18006988
1000: 1000 -0.6973182 -1.88854602
```

---

Confirming correct values:

```
# first n values
n <- 5
for (i in seq(n))
  a[seq(i, length.out=10), print(sum(value))]

#  [1] 1.322028
#  [1] 3.460263
#  [1] 3.666463
#  [1] 3.880851
#  [1] 0.07087005
```

---

#### BENCHMARKS (against for loop, so not quite fair)

```
set.seed(1)
a <- data.table(Date = 1:1000, value = rnorm(1000))

system.time({    a[ , lagSum := 
           a[, list(sum=sum(value)), by=list(grp=(Date+lag-i) %/% lag)] [grp!=0, sum]
       , by=list(i=Date %% lag)]
})

#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.049   0.001   0.056 



set.seed(1)
a <- data.table(Date = 1:1000, value = rnorm(1000))

system.time({    for (i in seq(nrow(a)-lag+1))
      a[seq(i, length.out=10), lagSum := sum(value)]})

#  user  system elapsed 
# 1.526   0.019   2.220
```

Comment: Heh, thanks, this is a bit arcane for me. :-D But I will study how it works. :)